# How can I find and sort the indexes of the elements of an object in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, indexof

Updated Version of the Problem: my goal is to get the indexes of the of the element of this array, with the condition that the subelement param_name of key params will define the index of the object. For instance, object with key name 'caller1' should have a default index of 0, but since param_name is 'caller2' it will take index 1; similarly object 3 with key name 'caller3' will take index 0 since param_name is 'caller1'. For object 2 with key name 'caller2' since param_name is same as key name caller2 it will retain its default index of 1.

```
const array1 = [{
        name: 'caller1',
        cost: 12,
        params:[{param_name:'caller2',apparatus:'fittings'}]
      },
      {
        name: 'caller2',
        cost: 2,
        params:[{param_name:'caller2',apparatus:'fittings'}]
      },
      {
        name: 'caller3',
        cost: 12,
        params:[{param_name:'caller1',apparatus:'valves'}]
      }
    ];
    const results = []
    for (let j=0; j<array1.length;j++){
      results[j] = array1[j].findIndex(a => a.name==array1[j].name);
    }
    console.log(results);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. btw, it looks like that you want to take an object as array for finding. that does not work.

Comment: Not sure I understand the goal, the index of the element would be `j` with your sample code if `a` is the object / element from `array[j]`. So your array of indexes would just be `Object.keys(array1)`. If `a` is something else (another array for example) you need to clarify that and where it is coming from

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: I want to get the indexes of the objects in the array called array1 using the key name in each of the objects in the array. So, the array called results will be: results = [0,1,2].

Comment: @Isaac Then its just `Object.keys(array1)`

Comment: Next question is why? What is your use case?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - nice idea, but the result would be an array of strings.

Comment: @OriDrori which is what array indexes are anyway since that is what object properties are unless using Symbols etc. And any math needing done will coerce it to be a number. There was no mention of actually needing a number primitive

Comment: @PatrickEvans my goal is to use the framework to discriminately select the index of interest using an if conditional. But I have only presented a shorthand version of the problem; since I can easily create the conditional myself.

Comment: @Isaac - this is an [XyProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking us to solve the weird solution, instead of the actual problem.

Comment: @OriDrori kindly pardon me for the ambiguity in the previous version of the question, I have updated the question to reflect my final goal.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  I have updated the question to reflect my goal. I am sorry for the ambiguity in the previous version of the question.

Comment: @Nina Scholz I have updated the question to reflect my goal. I am sorry for the ambiguity in the previous version of the question

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I have updated the question to reflect my goal. I am sorry for the ambiguity in the previous version of the question

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated the question to reflect my goal. I am sorry for the ambiguity in the previous version of the question.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is to sort the array

Comment: So your result now with the update would be `[1,1,0]`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans you are correct

Comment: what if you habe more than one index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the property from `params` and use that as a search parameter to use when looping over the main array

```
var indexes = array1.map(element => {
  var nameToCheck = element.params[0].param_name;
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i].name == nameToCheck) {
      return i;
    }
  }
})
```

---

Demo

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: 'caller1',
    cost: 12,
    params: [{
      param_name: 'caller2',
      apparatus: 'fittings'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'caller2',
    cost: 2,
    params: [{
      param_name: 'caller2',
      apparatus: 'fittings'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'caller3',
    cost: 12,
    params: [{
      param_name: 'caller1',
      apparatus: 'valves'
    }]
  }
];

var indexes = array1.map(element => {
  var nameToCheck = element.params[0].param_name;
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i].name == nameToCheck) {
      return i;
    }
  }
})

console.log(indexes);
```

Note that if `params` actually contains more than 1 element you would need to account for that and decide which one you need to use and change the `element.params[0].param_name;` line accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the indices.

```js
const 
    array = [{ name: 'caller1', cost: 12, params: [{ param_name: 'caller2', apparatus: 'fittings' }] }, { name: 'caller2', cost: 2, params: [{ param_name: 'caller2', apparatus: 'fittings' }] }, { name: 'caller3', cost: 12, params: [{ param_name: 'caller1', apparatus: 'valves' }] }],
    map = new Map(array.map(({ name }, i) => [name, i])),
    result = array.map(({ params: [{ param_name }] }) => map.get(param_name));

console.log(result);
```